# Proper way to inject React Component onto page in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome Extension and I want to inject HTML into the page DOM using the content scripts. That is easy, but I also want the content script to be a React component and the JS itself does not need to interact with the page JavaScript context, so that makes it simpler. I have a simple way to inject a container element into the DOM that my React code can render to, but I feel like it is very hacky and so I was wondering if there was an official way that React developers could suggest (Google was not particularly useful on this specific matter).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>App was injected.</h1>
  }
};

let container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute("id", "app-wrapper");
document.body.appendChild($el);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>, container);
```

Comment: What's hacky about it? `ReactDOM.render` requires an element to render to other than `document.body`, so you create the element via DOM API. Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that there was not a more official way of setting up the environment using the React API as opposed to generating the container with straight JS.

Comment: Hi @user3661841 , is the code you posted your content script? I can't import in the content script, I was wondering where in your app this code lived.

Comment: @Spothedog1 its been a while since I messed with this, but if I am remembering correctly, I used the chrome.tabs.executeScript API in the content script to inject the script onto the page. I am not sure if that is the correct API anymore since they have made some changes to how the extensions work.

Comment: @user3661841I figured it out thanks for replying. For anyone reading this I followed [this blog](https://blog.usejournal.com/making-an-interactive-chrome-extension-with-react-524483d7aa5d).

Answer (score 3):

I've found there's broadly two ways to do it. Both involve creating a new element somewhere in the `<body>` and attaching the `ReactDom.render` call to it.

1. Using content scripts - but this can be a headache for React (ejecting create-react-app and managing webpack)
2. Injecting the code directly from the Background.js script when a tab is active. To do this you can use `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. There is a short blog on it here: https://dev.to/anobjectisa/build-a-chrome-extension-using-reactjs-38o7

Answer (score 3):

This solution is based on: https://github.com/yosevu/react-content-script .

---

Inside `App.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Inside `content.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App'

const body = document.querySelector('body')
const app = document.createElement('div')

app.id = 'react-root'

if (body) {
  body.prepend(app)
}

const container = document.getElementById('react-root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(<App/>)  // Render react component
```

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: how to do you suggest to compile content.js and make it part of dist folder?

Answer (score -1):

Usually it's split into 2 files, one HTML and one JS. Something like this:

index.html

```
<head>
  <script src="path/to/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app-wrapper" />
</body>
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>App was injected.</h1>
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>, document.getElementById("app-wrapper"));
```

I don't know about an official way, but this is the implementation found in `create-react-app` and most of tutorials around.

Comment: The question mentions it's for a React extension, I don't believe this solution applies.